# What do you call the love of ancient ruins?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to find one word that describes the love of old building ruins.

Comment: Archaeo (ancient) + philia (love) = archaeophilia?

Comment: It’s a neologism (in that I just invented it and Google gives no hits whatsoever), but if you wish to be obscure and Greekish, you could call it _ereipiophilia_.

Comment: In keeping with the second definition for [*folly*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/folly?q=folly), perhaps *follyphilia*.

Comment: A folly is a new construction made to look like old ruins, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a rare neologism: **ruinophilia**.

The word *ruin* is originated from Latin *ruina*, but usually the part before the suffix *-philia* ends with "o" in philia words. (Latin suffix -o is usually used to form nominal compounds.)

Some examples:

> In contrast to postmodern fascination for multiplicity and simulation, **ruinophilia** mourns modern single-mindedness and utopian ambition.
>
> <sub>"Ruins of Modernity" edited by Julia Hell, Andreas Schönle (2010)</sub>

---

> Modern **ruinophilia** inevitably traced back to the Renaissance and the revival of antiquity, to the baroque, the upheavals of French Revolution, and the nineteenth-century development of archeology.
>
> <sub>"Writing Postcommunism: Towards a Literature of the East European Ruins" By David Williams (2013)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

[Ruin lust](http://www.theguardian.com/artanddesign/2012/feb/17/ruins-love-affair-decayed-buildings), is a possible definition:

> In 1953 Macaulay published Pleasure of Ruins, a lively and eccentric history of the *"ruin lust" that gripped European art and literature in the 18th century, reached its height in the romantic period, and had apparently declined in the first half of the 20th century in the face of wreckage that could not be turned to aesthetic or nostalgic advantage.*

Souce:http://www.theguardian.com/artanddesign/2012/feb/17/ruins-love-affair-decayed-buildings